# JAVA - Scanner parse by quotes AND comma

Tags: java, parsing, java.util.scanner

Trying to use scanner to parse a file from the following...

"dog","cat","horse","elephant","dolphin"

...have it output the following:

dog
cat
horse
elephant
dolphin

what scanner.useDelimiter regex can do this?  Maybe I not even on the right track.  What's the best way of getting these tokens without the comma between each token, and without the quotes on each token?

Comment: You're on the wrong track.  This sounds like a CSV file, for which there are several libraries that will do a good job.  Since you've provided no real details or code we can't really help beyond that.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use `Scanner` for this, instead I would:

```
List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"))) {
    String[] data = reader.readLine().split(",");
    for (String item : data) {
        values.add(item.replace("\"", ""));
    }
}
```

And you have those elements (only from the first line, but it is easy to extend it) in a list `values`.

Comment: You should put `BufferedReader` into [tag:try-with-resources] block to prevent memory leak

Comment: Guess I should have been more clear.  Commas could appear inside quotations.  For example, "dog","cat","horse","dol,phin" should parse to:  dog cat horse dol,phin

Comment: @Greymarch Then it would be better to use a CSV parser, if your data is compatible.

Comment: @Greymarch That is critical information that needs to be in your question.

Answer (score 0):

What you might be able do to start is set up a scanner to read the document, test using an if statement using scanner.hasNext() if the next string is a ' " ' or a ' , ' and passing by them(on "'s you could add a space), but if the scanner picks up on a alphabetical character, then print out the character. For some source code, here is a link to four explanations on how to parse through a text file or string.

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=87